# Jquery UI IFrame issues

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I have the following code which works well in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but in Safari it behaves slightly strangely.

In Safari if I move it or resize the iFrame I get a section of the main page and the popup iframe being selected / highlighted.

Does anyone know how to stop this ?

In the other browsers I can move or resize it very easily, Safari starts to select parts of the pages.

Also in all browsers, once the page has been resized if I close and reopen the page it opens at the resized state not the original state.. any way to change that.

```
<a href="test.php" id="fireIframe">Pick Me !!</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#fireIframe').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #iframeContent')
                .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 650,
                height: 500,
                title: 'Test'
            });
            $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW you have same IDs for multiple elements on a single page. Your code says this.

Comment: Thanks this is only a test, not a live page. The link etc works it's just the issue with Safari I have.